# How safe it is this rule?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase database question:
I want to "open" "votes" for unauthenticated users. Is this safe ?

> Maybe:

```
{
      "rules": {
        ".read": true,
              "posts": {
              "title": { ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == 'XXXXXX'"},
              "url": { ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == 'XXXXXX'"},
              "time": { ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == 'XXXXXX'"},
              "vote": {".write": true,}     
            }
      }
    }
```

> Or:

```
{
  "rules": {`enter code here`
    ".read": true,
          "posts": {
          "title": { ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == 'XXXXXX'"},
          "url": { ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == 'XXXXXX'"},
          "time": { ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == 'XXXXXX'"},
          "vote": {".write": "newData.val() === data.val() + 1"}     
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Since we don't know what you're trying to accomplish, we can't really say if it's "safe" by your requirements.  You might want to back and explain what your app is doing, and what you intend to allow and prevent from it.

Comment: I want: Read: All, Write (title,url and time: admin only), and Write (Vote: for all) and question is how safe is that open

Comment: i dont care about vote, i want to know is post title and url safe

Comment: Did you test your rules in the console simulator to check that they work the way you expect? Seems like that's going to be better than asking everyone if they think they work the way you want.

Comment: code is working... question is not about that. I want to know: Can someone do shady stuff outuside "vote"

Comment: Did you try to test possible shady behavior using the Firebase console rules simulator?

Comment: That is a very broad question and I am not sure can be answered. You may need to do some legwork yourself and research securing firebase, hacking firebase, etc. I just dis and quite a bit of links came up. Securing an app or a database is quite complicated. Not knowing anything about the rest of the application it's hard to assess safety. Please be more specific  than "shady stuff"....

Comment: Way too broad of a question without understanding the use case. However, and this is the important part, if you 'open' any node to an *unauthenticated user*, they can read, write delete that node however many times they want, so it's a bad idea in general. And... this `"vote": {".write": "newData.val() === data.val() + 1"}  ` doesn't guarantee anything other than your vote node is being incremented by only 1. That node could be incremented by 1 multiple times.